# How to handle "Call to a member function on a non object"

Tags: php

How do you ensure that you don't get a "Call to a member function on a non object" fatal ?

Fox example, I often have something like this in my templates: (which I find very convenient and readable):

```
<?php echo $object->getRelatedObject()->getProperty()->formatProperty() ?>
```

However, this will work only if each method returns an object of correct class. But it is not always the case. Related object may not be present in the database, so it returns null and you are faced with a fatal error. Then you go and manually check the return values:

```
<?php if (is_object($object->getRelatedObject()) && is_object($object->getRelatedObject()->getProperty())):
  <?php echo $object->getRelatedObject()->getPreperty()->formatProperty() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this isn't so readable anymore. How do you address this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`method_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to make sure a specific method exist in an object or class.

**Example:**

```
method_exists($object->getRelatedObject(), 'getProperty');
```

---

You could also add an interface to the returned relatedObjects and/or property objects to make sure they do have the required methods. For the cases where the call would usually return `NULL`, change it to a [`NullObject`](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) that has this method.

It's also questionable if chaining from `$object` all the way down to `formatProperty` is a good idea. Your `$object` requires intimate knowledge of the call graph there. You could consider [hiding the delegate](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/hideDelegate.html) from the related object and move `formatProperty` onto the `relatedObject` to get and format in one go or allow getting the property with a formatting flag.

Answer (score 2):

Each method can always throw an exception in the circumstance where it doesn't have an object to return. You then wrap your

```
echo $object->getRelatedObject()->getProperty()->formatProperty();
```

in a try/catch block

Comment: And probably SHOULD throw an exception if it has no object to return, given a name like get*Object().

Comment: I would love to see a web designer's face when he stumbes across a try/catch block in a template..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$relatedObject = $object->getRealtedObject();
if(is_object($relatedObject)){
    $property = $relatedObject->getProperty();
    if(is_object(property)){
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result="record not found";
if(is_object($object->getRelatedObject()) && 
   is_object($object->getRelatedObject()->getProperty()))
{
  $result=$object->getRelatedObject()->getPreperty()->formatProperty();
}
echo $result;
?>
```

thats a bit more readable :p

Comment: Thanks, but what I needed is a readable template solution, not a plain php script. In the example, I used php as a template language (isn't it apparent?)